# React 404 page with Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404

I have a problem showing 404 page in react
i have read all the related questions in stackoverflow but mine is a little different.
my code is like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Route} from "react-router";
import {Switch, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


export default class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>

                    <Route path={"/panel"} render={() =><span>Panel Page</span>}/>
                    <Route path={"panel/link1"} exact render={() => <h1>Link1 is OPEN</h1>}/>
                    <Route path="*" render={() => <h1>Not Found!</h1>}/>

                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

"Not Found" Component just works for any undefined urls **Not starting** with **"/panel/"** (beacuse that Route is not exact)
but i want it to work also for urls like  **: /panel/undefined**
please help me with this.

Comment: What if you put exact with /panel route too ? Wouldnt that solve your issue ?

Comment: for "/panel", <span>Panel Page</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try this option

```
<Router>
                <Switch>

                    <Route path={"/panel"} exact render={() =><span>Panel Page</span>}/>
                    <Route path={"panel/link1"} exact render={() => <h1>Link1 is OPEN</h1>}/>
                    <Route render={() => <h1>Not Found!</h1>}/>

                </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: it caused this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Comment: I don't want to use "Switch" because more than one Routs may be visible in one time